# Wordpress How make filter to return author_name in Wordpress API

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

how can i make a filter to return author name
i tried this code:

```
function get_author_name() {
    register_rest_field( 'post',
        'author_name',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'get_author_name'
        )
    );
}
function get_author_name( $object ) {
    return the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' , $object['author'] );
}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'get_author_name', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You can't redefine wp functions: `get_author_name`, you also defined `get_author_name` twice in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, this will add a `author_name` field in API response:

```
if(!function_exists('add_post_autor_field')){
    function add_post_autor_field($response, $post) {
        $response->data['author_name'] = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' , $post->author );
        return $response;
    }
}

add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'add_post_autor_field', 10, 3);
```